# Convert JSON IPython notebook (.ipynb) to .py file

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython, nbconvert

How do you convert an IPython notebook file (json with `.ipynb` extension) into a regular `.py` module?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I convert a IPython Notebook into a Python file via commandline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17077494/how-do-i-convert-a-ipython-notebook-into-a-python-file-via-commandline)

Answer (score 178, accepted):

From the notebook menu you can save the file directly as a python script. Go to the 'File' option of the menu, then select 'Download as' and there you would see a 'Python (.py)' option.

[image]

Another option would be to use nbconvert from the command line:

```
jupyter nbconvert --to script 'my-notebook.ipynb'
```

Have a look [here](http://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#convert-script).

Comment: An additional way to call nbconvert it is to do it automatically on save with the jupyter_notebook_confg.py file -- See http://stackoverflow.com/a/25765194/1653571

Comment: I don't seem to have ipython or jupyter installed, so I'm unaware of how to get to the notebook menu.

Comment: @DaveGoldsmith Run `pip install jupyter`. Once it's installed, go to your project directory and run `jupyter notebook`. It should open a web browser automatically, otherwise open one and go to `http://localhost:8888/notebooks/` to start creating or working with notebooks.

Comment: Is there a way in which I can get the output text also in a.py file

Comment: Doesn't work with `ipython [8.7.0]`. Returns warnings: `Unrecognized alias: 'to', it will have no effect.` and `File 'nbconvert' doesn't exist`

Comment: On newer versions of Jupyter, it appears that the wrapping quotes are not required, so to achieve the same result the command should be 

`jupyter nbconvert --to script my-notebook.ipynb`

Answer (score 41):

According to https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/notebook/nbconvert.html you are looking for the nbconvert command with the --to script option.

```
ipython nbconvert notebook.ipynb --to script
```

EDIT:

as per the comments, this is now updated to

```
jupyter nbconvert mynotebook.ipynb --to python
```

Comment: Getting this notice now, FYI: 
`[TerminalIPythonApp] WARNING | Subcommand 'ipython nbconvert' is deprecated and will be removed in future versions.
[TerminalIPythonApp] WARNING | You likely want to use 'jupyter nbconvert' in the future`

Comment: @Matt ipython has been renamed to jupyter. The message is telling you that the old executable name is deprecated. The convert command itself isn't.

Comment: @Adam, I understand that. I wanted to document the correct executable.

Answer (score 39):

**In short:** This command-line option converts `mynotebook.ipynb` to `python` code:

`jupyter nbconvert mynotebook.ipynb --to python`

**note:** this is different from [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37799104/147019) answer. `ipython` has been renamed to `jupyter`. the old executable name (ipython) is deprecated.

---

**More details:**
`jupyter` command-line has an `nbconvert` argument which helps convert notebook files `(*.ipynb)` to various other formats.

You could even convert it to any one of these formats using the same command but different `--to` option:

- asciidoc
- custom
- html
- latex. (Awesome if you want to paste code in conference/journal papers).
- markdown
- notebook
- pdf
- python
- rst
- script
- slides. (Whooh! Convert to slides for easy presentation )

the same command `jupyter nbconvert --to latex mynotebook.ipynb`

For more see `jupyter nbconvert --help`. There are extensive options to this. You could even to execute the code first before converting, different log-level options etc.

Comment: This is not really different than @Kush's answer, just the command name has changed since his answer.

Answer (score 17):

you can use this to do that :

```
pip install ipynb-py-convert
```

then run this on your terminal to convert .py file to .ipynb :

```
ipynb-py-convert Ex/abc.py Ex/abc.ipynb
```

to convert .ipynb files to .py :

```
ipynb-py-convert Ex/abc.ipynb Ex/abc.py
```

Answer (score 6):

You can run a .py file in the same directory:

```
import json

files = ["my_first_file_name.ipynb", "my_second_file_name.ipynb"]

for file in files:
    code = json.load(open(file))
    py_file = open(f"{file}.py", "w+")

    for cell in code['cells']:
        if cell['cell_type'] == 'code':
            for line in cell['source']:
                py_file.write(line)
            py_file.write("\n")
        elif cell['cell_type'] == 'markdown':
            py_file.write("\n")
            for line in cell['source']:
                if line and line[0] == "#":
                    py_file.write(line)
            py_file.write("\n")

    py_file.close()
```

I rewrite this code from Syrtis Major's answer.

Comment: The best answer available. Does not need `jupyter nbconvert` and just uses the standard json format to get the notebooks. Absolutely Brilliant!

Answer (score 4):

well first of all you need to install this package below:

```
sudo apt install ipython
jupyter nbconvert --to script [YOUR_NOTEBOOK].ipynb
```

two options are available either --to python or --to=python

for me this works fine:

```
jupyter nbconvert --to python while.ipynb 

[NbConvertApp] Converting notebook while.ipynb to python
[NbConvertApp] Writing 758 bytes to while.py

pip3 install ipython
```

if it does not work for you try, by pip3.

```
pip3 install ipython
```

Answer (score 4):

Tested on ***[Ubuntu 20.04](https://releases.ubuntu.com/20.04/)***

Install required packages for PIP

```
$ pip install ipython
$ pip install nbconvert
```

To install required packages

```
$ sudo apt-get install texlive-xetex texlive-fonts-recommended texlive-plain-generic
```

## METHOD 1

Use ***[jupyter nbconvert](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html)*** command to convert to different format

Source file pro.ipynb

[image: pro.ipynb]

- To convert to [ascii](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)

  ```
  $ jupyter nbconvert --to asciidoc pro.ipynb
  ```
- To convert to [pdf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF)

  ```
  $ jupyter nbconvert --to pdf pro.ipynb
  ```
- To convert to [python](https://www.python.org/)

  ```
  $ jupyter nbconvert --to python pro.ipynb
  ```

## METHOD 2

Convert ipynb project through python code use ***[savefig](http://import%20matplotlib.pyplot%20as%20plt%20%25matplotlib%20inline%20exp_vals=%5B1400,600,300,410,250%5D%20exp_labels=%5B%27Home%20Rent%27,%27Food%27,%27Phone/Internet%20Bill%27,%27Car%27,%27Other%20Utilities%27%5D%20plt.axis(%27equal%27)%20plt.pie(exp_vals,labels=exp_labels,radius=2,autopct=%27%250.1f%25%25%27,shadow=True,explode=%5B0,0.5,0,0.3,0%5D,startangle=20)%20#%20plt.show()%20plt.savefig(%27piechart.jpg%27,bbox_inches=%27tight%27,pad_inches=2,transparent=True,edgecolor=%27r%27))*** method of ***[pyplot](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot)***:

### pro.ipynb

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
exp_vals=[1400,600,300,410,250]
exp_labels=['Home Rent','Food','Phone/Internet Bill','Car','Other Utilities']
plt.axis('equal')
plt.pie(exp_vals,labels=exp_labels,radius=2,autopct='%0.1f%%',shadow=True,explode=[0,0.5,0,0.3,0],startangle=20)
# plt.show()
plt.savefig('piechart.jpg',bbox_inches='tight',pad_inches=2,transparent=True,edgecolor='r')
```

piechart.png image that it generated:

[image: piechart.png]

```
   Hope this helps to convert your ~(`)/\/\/\_ [Python] code
```

Answer (score 3):

You definitely can achieve that with nbconvert using the following command:

```
jupyter nbconvert --to python while.ipynb
```

However, having used it personally I would advise against it for several reasons:

1. It's one thing to be able to convert to simple Python code and another to have all the right abstractions, classes access and methods set up. If the whole point of you converting your notebook code to Python is getting to a state where your code and notebooks are maintainable for the long run, then nbconvert alone will not suffice. The only way to do that is by manually going through the codebase.
2. Notebooks inherently promote writing code which is not maintainable (https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1n2RlMdmv1p25Xy5thJUhkKGvjtV-dkAIsUXP-AL4ffI/edit#slide=id.g3d7fe085e7_0_21). Using nbconvert on top might just prove to be a bandaid. Specific examples of where it promotes not-so-maintainable code are imports might be sprayed throughout, hard coded paths are not in one simple place to view, class abstractions might not be present, etc.
3. nbconvert still mixes execution code and library code.
4. Comments are still not present (probably were not in the notebook).
5. There is still a lack of unit tests etc.

So to summarize, there is not good way to out of the box convert python notebooks to maintainable, robust python modularized code, the only way is to manually do surgery.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following script to convert jupyter notebook to Python script, or view the code directly.

To do this, write the following contents into a file `cat_ipynb`, then `chmod +x cat_ipynb`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import json

for file in sys.argv[1:]:
    print('# file: %s' % file)
    print('# vi: filetype=python')
    print('')
    code = json.load(open(file))

    for cell in code['cells']:
        if cell['cell_type'] == 'code':
            print('# -------- code --------')
            for line in cell['source']:
                print(line, end='')
            print('\n')
        elif cell['cell_type'] == 'markdown':
            print('# -------- markdown --------')
            for line in cell['source']:
                print("#", line, end='')
            print('\n')
```

Then you can use

`cat_ipynb your_notebook.ipynb > output.py`

Or show it with `vi` directly

`cat_ipynb your_notebook.ipynb | view -`

Answer (score 2):

If this is a one-off, follow e.g. @kikocorreoso depending if you want to use command line or gui.

However, if you want some solution that will maintain a synchronized version of the .py and the .ipynb you really should consider using [jupytext](https://jupytext.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using-cli.html) as also pointed out by @Wayne

Run `conda install jupytext`  or `pip install jupytext`

Then do:
`jupytext --set-formats ipynb,py <file>.ipynb`

To keep it synchronized to the .py file:

`jupytext --set-formats ipynb,py <file>.ipynb --sync`

This will make sure jupyter keeps the two files in sync when saving from now on...

Last note: If you are a gui person, after running the installation command for jupytext, everything else can be done from the gui as well `File-->Jupytext-->pair Notebook with light Script`:
[image]

Comment: the comma in `ipynb,py` haunts me

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to https://jupyter.org/
2. click on nbviewer
3. Enter the location of your file and render it.
4. Click on view as code (shown as < />)

Comment: Please elaborate steps 3 and 4.

Comment: @JJJ It is detailed at the link. For 3, I, for instance, had the jupyter notebook on a Git repository and just entered the link to the file on git. For 4, after opening your notebook, on top right, you find few icons. The icon with </> on it is "view as code" icon. Hope this clarifies.

Answer (score 1):

Jupytext allows for such a conversion on the command line, and **importantly you can go back again from the script to a notebook** (even an executed notebook). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59568527/8508004).

Answer (score 1):

One way to do that would be to upload your script on Colab and download it in .py format from `File -> Download .py`

Answer (score 1):

Convert the Ipynb dir files to .py

```py
import os

for fname in os.listdir():
    if fname.endswith('ipynb'):
        os.system(f'jupyter nbconvert {fname} --to python')
```

Comment: I didnot get file

Comment: make sure you have jupyter notebook installed

Comment: $ pip install ipython
$ pip install nbconvert

Comment: This is just the same as the other solution but you're running the bash command from inside python.

Comment: @emilBeBri it's for converting multiple files in one attempt.

Comment: right, I guess it's good to have different ways of doing it, sorry for being a bit of a dick.

Answer (score 1):

```
jupyter nbconvert [filename].ipynb --no-prompt --to python
```

The above code will generate [filename].py in the same directory

Answer (score 0):

**Copy all the (''.ipynb) files in the Desired folder then execute:**

```
import os    

desired_path = 'C:\\Users\\Docs\\Ipynb Covertor'

os.chdir(desired_path)

list_of_directory = os.listdir(desired_path)

for file in list_of_directory:
        os.system('ipython nbconvert --to script ' + str(file))
```

Answer (score 0):

My version of Jupyter Notebook, 3.3.2, has this option on the File Menu:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

## Use VS Code

1. Step 1 : Open your .ipynb file in vs code.
2. Step 2 : Click on export [Screenshot of where the option is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnbiI.png).
3. Step 3 : Click on Python Script [Screenshot of export types](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLvd1.png).
   Now VS Code will open your file as a python script in a new tab with an untitled name.
4. Now press `Ctrl + s` to save it to wherever you want.

Comment: While I haven't verified if VS Code can handle the conversion, I believe that recommending the installation of a feature-rich IDE like VS Code for a straightforward conversion might be excessive. Unless the question explicitly mentions the use of VS Code, a more lightweight and focused tool could be a more suitable recommendation for the specific task at hand.

Comment: @tidakdiinginkan while that may be true, it is a helpful suggestions for those already running notebooks in VSCode. Thanks Sandupa, helped me out :)

Comment: @RogerKint a solution that caters to everyone wins over specific toolset solutions. Had the OP mentioned VSCode specifically, this solution would have made sense. good for you that this solves your specific case.