# how to combine ".ipynb" files to ".py" modules

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, matplotlib

```
import ipynb
```

As I m doing on data visualization programme in ipynb, how to import .ipynb to .py modules and how to present data visual charts in .py modules

Comment: What do you mean by `combine`? Do you want your `.ipynb` code in `.py` or something else?

Comment: ya i want to use .ipynb code in .py.

Comment: If you are using `jupyter notebook`, then it's pretty easy. Follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37797709/convert-json-ipython-notebook-ipynb-to-py-file.

Comment: I want to data visualize in .py  as a image (jpg)

Answer (score 2):

You can convert your notebook with this command

```
ipython nbconvert --to python namefile.ipynb
```

You might have to install mistune through pip for exmaple

If you want to import the code from your notebook to a .py file, you might want to check this out http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/jupyter/notebook/blob/master/docs/source/examples/Notebook/Importing%20Notebooks.ipynb

Hope this helps

Comment: I want to data visualize in .py also

Comment: @VEERESHNB the data visualization is an other problem, you should create a new question