# what's the problem to my file extentions (.ipynb , .py)

Tags: python, file, jupyter-notebook

I changed the extension of the file after working on the `jupyter notebook`.
(`.ipynb -> .py`)
After that I got a problem.
I can not go back to try to go back to the `.ipynb` with strange files. 
How can someone help me? :j

[image]

Comment: Add error message here instead of putting image

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37797709/convert-json-ipython-notebook-ipynb-to-py-file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [convert json ipython notebook(.ipynb) to .py file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37797709/convert-json-ipython-notebook-ipynb-to-py-file)

Answer (score 0):

If you mean changing just the extension then it wont..it's like saving the features of ipynb notebook to .py file. Instead you can download the IPYNB as PY file on Jupyter notebook itself..