# How to get the raw contents of a Jupyerlab notebook .ipynb file?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

Lets say I have a jupyter notebook .ipynb file created, with a cell block of type *code* and type *markdown*. If I open the file to see the **raw** contents, I see something like this

```
{
 "cells": [
  {
   "cell_type": "code",
   "execution_count": 2,
   "id": "f0e5fd3c-73ce-4772-acba-ec62dbbc4a90",
   "metadata": {},
   "outputs": [
    {
     "name": "stdout",
     "output_type": "stream",
     "text": [
      "hello world\n"
     ]
    }
   ],
   "source": [
    "print(\"hello world\")"
   ]
  },
  {
   "cell_type": "raw",
   "id": "b9d6d461-d25d-4ae1-b806-5f2c0d3c8332",
   "metadata": {},
   "source": [
    "this is normal text"
   ]
  }
 ],
 "metadata": {
  "kernelspec": {
   "display_name": "Python 3 (ipykernel)",
   "language": "python",
   "name": "python3"
  },
  "language_info": {
   "codemirror_mode": {
    "name": "ipython",
    "version": 3
   },
   "file_extension": ".py",
   "mimetype": "text/x-python",
   "name": "python",
   "nbconvert_exporter": "python",
   "pygments_lexer": "ipython3",
   "version": "3.10.4"
  }
 },
 "nbformat": 4,
 "nbformat_minor": 5
}
```

How would I go about programmatically getting the raw contents of a current notebook that is being worked on? Is such a thing possible? I've tried looking into the JupyterLab Contents API and IPython but can't seem to find a solution to get the raw contents of the file. Any help or advice is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [convert json ipython notebook(.ipynb) to .py file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37797709/convert-json-ipython-notebook-ipynb-to-py-file)

Comment: Simply write some Python code to read the notebook file contents as you would for a standard text file or JSON file.

Answer (score 0):

There is a button to export it. For example, opening it in vscode, beside the variables in the top right of the screen, there are 3 dots. Click on that > export > Python Script

Comment: Sorry, I should've specified in the title. I'm looking for a way to programmatically get the raw contents of the file.

Comment: I see, well it is still easy to implement since it follows the same format **for j in k['cells']:
  x = j['source'] print(x)**  a simple loop would give you flexibility over what you want to choose, which in this case is the content and that is stored in the ['source'] of each cell

Comment: Could you please elaborate? Where is the k['cells'] and j['source'] coming from here?

Comment: k is a any variable that holds all the data of the ipynb (in this case the one you linked). Now, when initiating the loop, you have to enter the dictionary 'cell' (the first value of the dictionary). Next, [] indicates that you are navigating through lists, so you each **List** using j, which is stored in the **dictionary** cells. Finally, in the list you are navigating in you choose the dictionary called source, since it has the information needed.

Comment: @March_G, I think you forgot to mention `nbformat`? @Jenny_C, see the very top of my reply [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71244733/edit) (~top three parapgraphs) to start learning about `nbformat`. I have a number of examples [posted at the Jupyter Discourse Forum here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/search?q=nbformat%20%40fomightez) of programmatically parsing notebooks by iterating on the cells in the notebook using `nbformat`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import codecs

jupyter_file = codecs.open(filePath, 'r')
source_data = jupyter_file.read()

print(source_data)
```

`source_data` gives the raw content of `.ipynb` file as a JSON string. You can use `json.loads()` to parse that string and use it or `dump` it in a separate file as you need.

Comment: Did you try this? @Jenny C