# Converting .py files to .ipynb

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, nbconvert

My organisation converts any Jupyter Notebooks (.ipynb files) it makes into python scripts (.py files) for easier management in our repos. I need to convert them back so I can run the notebooks but can't work out how.

I believe they've been encoded using the `nbconvert` package but I couldn't find a way to convert the files back in the package docs.

I've included the head of one of the .py files bellow in case it makes the encoding format more obvious.

```
# ---
# jupyter:
#   jupytext:
#     formats: ipynb,py:light
#     text_representation:
#       extension: .py
#       format_name: light
#       format_version: '1.4'
#       jupytext_version: 1.2.0
#   kernelspec:
#     display_name: Python 3
#     language: python
#     name: python3
# ---

# # Title/filename here

# ### Initialise

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# etc


# ### Title here

# + 
do_stuff()
```

Comment: Does this help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37797709/convert-json-ipython-notebook-ipynb-to-py-file

Comment: I believe that's the other way around (.ipynb -> .py) but I need .py -> .ipynb. Thanks

Comment: Alright I read your question opposite I'll keep looking

Comment: ```pip install p2j``` the ```p2j myfile.py``` could work? I'd try to make sure the encoding matches

Comment: Thanks @MATOS but looks like it wasn't encoded using p2j, and I don't have admin rights to install it anyhow. I think I've answered my own question though now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the file was actually converted using program `jupytext`.

To convert it back I found running `jupytext --to ipynb my_file.py` worked.

More simply: opening the .py file in `jupyter notebook` allowed me to view the .py file as if it were a .ipynb file without converting.

Comment: "More simply: opening the .py file in jupyter notebook allowed me to view the .py file as if it were a .ipynb file without converting."

Sneaky. I will try this. Thanks