# Converting .ipynb to .py in colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

Is there a simple way to do this? I have a `.ipynb` file I want to convert to a python module and import it, hence want to make it into a `.py` file. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Have you looked at: [Convert JSON IPython notebook (.ipynb) to .py file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37797709/convert-json-ipython-notebook-ipynb-to-py-file)

Comment: @JonSG Was hoping for a more recent answer and something with less friction that I could do in colab.

Answer (score 3):

In [google colab](https://colab.research.google.com/), you can simply do this:

[image]

The above will convert your notebook (`.ipynb`) to a python script (`.py`).

**Alternatively,** you can run the following command in a cell:

```
!jupyter nbconvert my-notebook.ipynb --to python
```

The above will generate a python script, `my-notebook.py` keeping the original filename.