# I am looking for a simple way to extract python code from a notebook on kaggle?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, kaggle

I am new to Kaggle and using notebooks. I can see that I can fork notebooks on Kaggle, however, whenever I try to get the code by clicking on the Code tab, it provides the necessary python commands for analysis (which I want) along with a lot of code to produce the formatted text that shows up in the Notebook(which I don't want).

I was wondering if there was an easy way to just extract the python code needed for analysis, without  all of the code meant to format the Notebook output. Could anyone help me with this?  I suspect it must be simple, but I searched around for a while and couldn't seem to find what I was looking for. Thanks for your time.

Comment: You need to use jupyter for the easiest ways

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. Visit the kernel you wish to retrieve the code of.
2. Fork the kernel which will take you to an editor mode.
3. From the editor mode, download the Ipython notebook.
4. Run following command to convert the notebook into a python script and enjoy the code. `!jupyter nbconvert --to script config_template.ipynb`

For clear information on point 4, have a look on this webpage https://stackoverflow.com/a/19779226/10734525

Comment: This Works! Thanks!

Comment: Great. Keep upvoting and accepting helpful answers ;)