# Automatically convert jupyter notebook to .py

Tags: python, bash, automation, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I know there have been a few questions about this but I have not found anything robust enough.

Currently I am using, from terminal, a command that creates .py, then moves them to another folder:

```
jupyter nbconvert --to script '/folder/notebooks/notebook.ipynb' &&  \
mv ./folder/notebooks/*.py ./folder/python_scripts && \
```

The workflow then is to code in a notebook, check with `git status` what changed since last commit, create a potentially huge number of `nbconvert` commands, then move them all.

I would like to use something like `!jupyter nbconvert --to script`found [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19779226/6028947), but without the cell that crates the python file appearing in the .py itself.

Because if that line appears, my code won't ever work right.

So, is there a proper way of dealing with this problem? One that can be automated, and not manually copying files names, creating the command, executing and then starting again.

Answer (score 5):

Another way would be to use [Jupytext](https://github.com/mwouts/jupytext) as extension for your jupyter installation (can be easily pip installed).

> **Jupytext Description** (see github page)
>
> Have you always wished Jupyter notebooks were plain text documents?
>   Wished you could edit them in your favorite IDE? And get clear and
>   meaningful diffs when doing version control? Then... Jupytext may well
>   be the tool you're looking for!

It will keep paired notebooks in sync with `.py` files. You then just need to move your `.py` files or gitignore the notebooks for example as possible workflows.

Comment: Please consider elaborating on your link reference.

Comment: Really helpful answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can add the following code **in the last cell** in your notebook file.

```
!jupyter nbconvert --to script mycode.ipynb
with open('mycode.py', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
with open('mycode.py', 'w') as f:
    for line in lines:
        if 'nbconvert --to script' in line:
            break
        else:
            f.write(line)
```

It will generate the .py file and then remove this very code from it. You will end up with a clean script that will not call `!jupyter nbconvert` anymore.

Comment: I have seen solutions similar to this, the problem I have with this approach is, how to avoid this from appearing in the script? Meaning, the idea is to automate the execution of the .py file. That .py will still have this code, right? If it does, it is not going to work very well for my purposes of automation

Comment: No, the py file will not have the code. Try it out.

Comment: is there a typo in the if statement?

Comment: @mLstudent33 what would be the typo?

Comment: actually it just looks greyed out but it's actually not a comment right?  `nbconvert --to script`...2 dashes on S.O. probably greys it out thinking it's a comment.

Comment: Yes, it's a string, I don't know why wasn't colored correctly

Answer (score 1):

Go to `File > Save and Export Notebook as... > Executable Scripts`

Comment: I guess the UI is version specific. My path is: ```File > Download as... > Python (.py)```

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extending/savehooks.html) is the closest I have found to what I had in mind, but I have yet to try and implement it:

```
   # A post-save hook to make a script equivalent whenever the notebook is saved (replacing the --script option in older versions of the notebook):

import io
import os
from notebook.utils import to_api_path

_script_exporter = None

def script_post_save(model, os_path, contents_manager, **kwargs):
    """convert notebooks to Python script after save with nbconvert

    replaces `jupyter notebook --script`
    """
    from nbconvert.exporters.script import ScriptExporter

    if model['type'] != 'notebook':
        return

    global _script_exporter

    if _script_exporter is None:
        _script_exporter = ScriptExporter(parent=contents_manager)

    log = contents_manager.log

    base, ext = os.path.splitext(os_path)
    script, resources = _script_exporter.from_filename(os_path)
    script_fname = base + resources.get('output_extension', '.txt')
    log.info("Saving script /%s", to_api_path(script_fname, contents_manager.root_dir))

    with io.open(script_fname, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        f.write(script)
```

c.FileContentsManager.post_save_hook = script_post_save

Additionally, [this](https://github.com/jupyterhub/jupyterhub/issues/1412) looks like it has worked to some user on github, so I put it here for reference:

```
import os
from subprocess import check_call

def post_save(model, os_path, contents_manager):
    """post-save hook for converting notebooks to .py scripts"""
    if model['type'] != 'notebook':
        return # only do this for notebooks
    d, fname = os.path.split(os_path)
    check_call(['ipython', 'nbconvert', '--to', 'script', fname], cwd=d)
```