# Convert a jupyter notebook into a clean python file?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipython, jupyter

I want to convert a jupyter notebook to a clean python file.

I don't want the `# In[ ]:` comments in the generated python script, I want it to be clean.

Is there any way to do that?

I ran below command `jupyter nbconvert --to script --no-prompt notebook.ipynb` as mentioned in the comments of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19779226/5265615) but the generated script still contains `# In[ ]:` comments.

Generated script:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

# In[1]:


print("Hello World")


# In[2]:


print("Hello Jupyter")
```

Desired script:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

print("Hello World")

print("Hello Jupyter")
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: @Vishal There is no error. I am looking for a command to quickly generate a clean python script without `# In[ ]:` comments and its spacing according to [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). Both GUI and the command mentioned in the question do not give a clean script.

Comment: I tried with mine, and everything was clean.