# Type-check Jupyter Notebooks with mypy

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, mypy

I have a project containing a bunch of Python modules (`.py` files) and a bunch of Jupyter Notebooks (`.ipynb` files) which import things from the Python modules.

I can (assuming I've got `__init__.py` files in all subfolders) type-check all the `.py` files by simply running `mypy .` from the root of the project. But I'd like to also be able to type-check my Jupyter Notebooks.

An ideal solution would:

- type check all Python code in my Jupyter Notebooks,
- be able to follow imports of `.py` modules from within Jupyter Notebooks when type-checking, just like imports in `.py` files,
- let me type-check the whole project from the command line, so that I can run type-checking as part of a test suite or a pre-commit hook, and
- in some way meaningfully report the locations of type errors within my Notebooks, analogously to how mypy prints line numbers for errors in `.py` files.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 22):

You could use [nbQA](https://github.com/nbQA-dev/nbQA) and do

```sh
pip install -U nbqa
nbqa mypy your_notebook.ipynb
```

Comment: This answer is great as it provides a general solution to the problem of running linters/formatters/etc on notebooks. Thanks for writing it @ignoring_gravity!

Comment: Thanks @erb  , much appreciated! Version 0.7.0 has just come out, it has a few fixes for mypy

Answer (score 6):

Checkout [nb-mypy](https://pypi.org/project/nb-mypy/)

`Nb Mypy` is a facility to automatically run mypy on Jupyter notebook cells as they are executed, whilst retaining information about the execution history.

More details [here](https://gitlab.tue.nl/jupyter-projects/nb_mypy/-/blob/master/Nb_Mypy.ipynb)

Answer (score 5):

You can:
Convert all notebooks to python, then run mypy on that ([How do I convert a IPython Notebook into a Python file via commandline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17077494/how-do-i-convert-a-ipython-notebook-into-a-python-file-via-commandline)).

```
jupyter nbconvert --to script [YOUR_NOTEBOOK].ipynb
```

Just write a small script to do this and you are fine :)

Answer (score 3):

I use [Jupytext](https://github.com/mwouts/jupytext) and my IDE for this.

I export a copy in py:percent format, link that to the notebook. I Do the development in the jupyter lab environment, but the `.py` file is the one that goes in the git repository. Before commiting, I run it throught the usual linters, `black`, `pydocstyle`, `mypy` (with a strict configuration). I then reload the notebook in Jupyter lab, restart the kernel and 'Run All' to make sure the results are still OK, and only then commit the file to the repository