# JuliaPro: import Jupiter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, julia, ijulia-notebook

I usually use Jupyter to have my interactive environment with Julia, now I am switching to [JuliaPro](https://juliacomputing.com), as they claim it is the fastest and easiest way of Julia programming. But, I cannot upload my .ipynb notebooks on JuliaPro. Are they compatible with each other? How can I work with my notebooks on JuliaPro? Thanks!

Comment: You need to use the IJulia.jl package.

Comment: I don't think you can really use a notebook based workflow on Juno, but maybe you could clarify your question a bit? What do you mean by import and what would the result be? Do you expect to be able to run cells in the Juno editor?

Comment: Exactly. Think of having a Jupyter notebook saved in the ipynb format, now how would you open this notebook in Juno, first to read it, then to process each cell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As was explained in the comments, the `.ipynb` file format was designed to be rendered in a browser, while Juno/Atom is a text editor that expects a plain text file for display. In general therefore you wouldn't be able to directly use an `.ipynb` file in Juno.

There is however an option to convert your notebooks to `.jl` scripts, which is exactly what Juno is expecting: in your Jupyter notebook click on File > Download as > Julia (.jl) (see below)

[image]

There's also an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17077494/how-do-i-convert-a-ipython-notebook-into-a-python-file-via-commandline) that discusses a command line option if you need to batch convert a lot of files.

Also note that your choice of editor / programming environment is unrelated to the version of Julia you're using - while JuliaPro ships with Juno as standard (or potentially the Julia VS Code extension in future), nothing's keeping you from just doing `using Pkg; Pkg.add("IJulia"); using IJulia; notebook()` in your JuliaPro installation and continuing to work on your notebooks in Jupyter.

Comment: Thanks Nils! This is very helpful.