# In Python : How to use a function local Variable in different file function

Tags: python, function

I have a function that is stored in Dates.ipynb and Second function is stored in function.ipynb file.

So in Dates.ipynb file there is function which name is `input_dates()`
dates.ipynb Code:

```
import datetime as dt
from datetime import datetime

def input_dates():
    global start_date
    global exit_date
    from_date = input("enter date to start from in YYYYMMDD format :")
    end_date = input("enter date to end in YYYYMMDD format :")
    start_date = datetime.strptime(from_date, '%Y%m%d').date()
    exit_date = datetime.strptime(end_date, '%Y%m%d').date()
    
input_dates()

def year():
    global from_year
    global end_year
    from_year = start_date.year
    end_year = exit_date.year
    
year()

def month():
    global from_month
    global end_month
    from_month = start_date.month
    end_month = exit_date.month
    
month()
```

Function.ipynb Code:

```
input_dates()

def path():
    while start_date <= exit_date:
        if from_date.month<10:
            path1 = (Fu_path + "\\" + str(from_year)+"\\" +str(from_month))
        else:
            path1 = (Fu_path + "\\" + str(from_year)+"\\"+str(from_month))
        from_date1 += relativedelta(months =+ 1)
        dir_list = os.listdir(path1)
        print(dir_list)

path()
```

Error:
[image]

So how can I use Dates.ipynb file function in function.ipynb file funcstions.

Comment: Despite the name, each module has a separate global namespace. If you import the module itself (with `import foo`, rather than `from module import specific_values`), you'll be able to access the other module's global namespace via `module.global_name`.

Comment: @Blckknght can you please explain this in a coded form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**

In your case you should use the return capability of functions.

```py
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

FU_PATH = "foo" # You should change this to the correct path


def input_dates():
    from_date = input("Enter date to start from in YYYYMMDD format :")
    end_date = input("Enter date to end in YYYYMMDD format :")
    start_date = datetime.strptime(from_date, '%Y%m%d').date()
    exit_date = datetime.strptime(end_date, '%Y%m%d').date()
    return start_date, exit_date

start_date, exit_date = input_dates()


def path(start_date, exit_date):
    while start_date <= exit_date:
        # If-else statement is redundant, since it does the same thing
        if start_date.month < 10:
            path1 = (FU_PATH + "\\" + str(start_date.year) + "\\" + str(start_date.month))
        else:
            path1 = (FU_PATH + "\\" + str(start_date.year) + "\\" + str(start_date.month))
        start_date += relativedelta(months =+ 1)
        dir_list = os.listdir(path1)
        print(dir_list)

path(start_date, exit_date)
```

**Initial response answer**

Functions don't have attributes you can access like this. This behavior you can get with classes.

For example:

```py
class MyClass:
    my_variable = 1
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

```py
YourClass = MyClass() 
print(YourClass.my_variable)
```

> 1

Side note, try not to use global variables. It is your last resort, but in general there are always better and more elegant solutions.

Comment: What can i use place of global? actually I'm a new in programming.

Comment: And this class method is also not working.

Answer (score 1):

You can't between `.ipynb` files. But there are many ways you can use jupyter to save one (or both) of the files into `.py` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17077494/how-do-i-convert-a-ipython-notebook-into-a-python-file-via-commandline) ).

You can then import the python file into your notebook and use the functions it contains.

Comment: I think you didn't understand my question. I can access the function, but in my code, I'm doing something wrong so that's why I can't access the local variable. I'm a beginner in programming so maybe I'm doing something wrong in functions.

Comment: And i run the same code in VS Code (.py) file but this is not working in VS code also.