# How to run a Jupyter notebook .ipynb in python file .py?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I have some Jupyter notebooks and I want them to be executed using a main.py file.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the `.ipynb` file to a plain `.py` file using any of the methods mentioned here -

[How do I convert a IPython Notebook into a Python file via commandline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17077494/how-do-i-convert-a-ipython-notebook-into-a-python-file-via-commandline)

If, like me, you don't have access to the command line tools required - you can extract the source code from the `.ipynb` file as it is mostly a `json` file

```
import json
with open('somefile.ipynb') as f:
    nb_content = json.load(f)

for cell in nb_content['cells']:
    print(*cell['source'])
```

That should print out the whole source code to your terminal