# Automating Python Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, scheduler, repeat

I would like to automate a python notebook to run every hour. I've tried the task scheduler via a .py file and looked at cron job etc but I think I am doing something incorrectly.

What would be the most simple effective way of doing the automation every hour?

Comment: The easiest way would probably be to [turn the notebook into a Python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17077494/how-do-i-convert-a-ipython-notebook-into-a-python-file-via-commandline), then run the script in a cron job.

Comment: Can you rephrase this question with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Hi Alexander , ive done that now as a .py file. I'll research up on cron jobs more thoroughly

Comment: There's a few ways to do this. The [schedule](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) library may also be appropriate if the script is refactored as a function.